# Manipulate Continuously Evaluates

Tags: manipulate

Paring a much more complicated example down I came to an MWE:

```
Manipulate[
 x = {a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
 x = {1, 0}*# & /@ x;
 , {a, 1, 10}
 ]
```

runs continuously - the cell bracket is black. The odd thing is:

```
Manipulate[
 x = {a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
 x = {1, 1}*# & /@ x;
 , {a, 1, 10}
 ]
```

does NOT run continuously. All I changed here is multiplication done in the second line.

The problem I'm running into is in a more complicated section of code where `Manipulate` ends up slowing to a crawl. In my complicated example I was able to fix the behavior by calculating each variable in a single line of computation. i.e.

```
Manipulate[
 x = {1, 0}*# & /@ ({a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}});
 , {a, 1, 10}
 ]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I suspect a bug. Mac 10.13.6 MMA ver 12.0.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you had

```
Manipulate[
 x = {a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
 x = {1, 0}*# & /@ x;
 , {a, 1, 10}
 ]
```

Then since `a=1` initially, then the first line `x = {a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}` produces `x={{1, 1}, {2, 2}}` and then the second line `x = {1, 0}*# & /@ x` produces `x={{1, 0}, {2, 0}}`, so `x` has changed. Because of this, and since you did not specify which symbol to track, then Manipulate reevaluated the expression again. And `x` changed again, and so on.

But when you had

```
Manipulate[
 x = {a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
 x = {1, 1}*# & /@ x;
 , {a, 1, 10}
 ]
```

And since `a=1` initially, then first line produces `x={{1, 1}, {2, 2}}` as before but now the second line gives `x={{1, 1}, {2, 2}}`, so `x` did not change. So no need to re evaluate Manipulate expression again.

Solution is to always use tracked symbols option to tell Manipulate explicitly which symbol to track its changes.

```
Manipulate[
 x = {a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
 x = {1, 0}*# & /@ x;
 ,
 {a, 1, 10},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a}]
```

Now it works OK

Answer (score 4):

The reason the continuous updating happens is that the Manipulate is being re-evaluated each time any of its variables changes. In this case, you have x = (some function of x), and so it continuously updates. A simple fix is:

```
Manipulate[y = {a, a}*# & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
x = {1, 1}*# & /@ y, {a, 1, 10}]
```

Now it seems stable in all the cases.